# I got a lot of error when trying to tranfer my verilog code from modelsim to quartus

Tags: verilog, fpga, modelsim, quartus

Hi guys I built a simple design in modelsim with a lot of verilog file. I am trying to get a RTL schematic so i want to tranfer my project to quartus. But i got a lot of errors even my code run ok on modelsim.

```
module OR_64BITS (out, in1, in2);
  input wire [63:0] in1, in2;
  output wire [63:0] out;
  
  genvar i;
    generate
        for (i = 0; i < 64; i = i + 1) begin
      or (out[i], in1[i], in2[i]);
        end
    endgenerate 
endmodule
```

i got this error Error (10644): Verilog HDL error at basic_components_2.v(9): this block requires a name
on this line

```
for (i = 0; i < 64; i = i + 1) begin
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any problems here, although I don't have access to Quartus. Is this a recent-ish version of Quartus? If Quartus is insistent on a name, try changing the line to `for (i = 0; i < 64; i = i + 1) begin: a_name`  although I don't think the standard requires this.

Comment: @DavidShah It seems another tool "spyglass lint" (maybe this?) will treat `generate` block without a block name as an error too.

Comment: @Light spyglass lint?

Comment: Your code is compatible with Verilog-2005, but not Verilog-2001. It seems like Quartus is expecting Verilog-2001, whereas Modelsim is fine with Verilog-2005. The requirement to name your generate block was removed in Verilog-2005.

Answer (score 1):

I have a verilog standard pdf file with the version: IEEE Std 1364-2001, 28 September 2001.

In it, I can find the standard BNF definition for `generate`-`for` block:

```
generate_loop_statement ::=
  for ( genvar_assignment ; constant_expression ; genvar_assignment )
    begin : generate_block_identifier { generate_item } end
```

According to it, the `: generate_block_identifier` part is required.

You can modify your code as @David Shah suggested in comment. Add `: a_uniq_block_name` to that `for(...)` line.

EDIT:
I have this verilog-2001 standard doc only. As @Matthew Taylor commented, this requirement has been removed in IEEE Std 1364-2005. Maybe you can find which standard version your quartus comply with in some deep dialogs.

Comment: The requirement for `: generate_block_identifier` was removed in IEEE Std 1364-2005.

Comment: Even though the requirement was removed, it's still a good idea to name all your blocks, and give primitive instances names as well (missing in your `or` gate). Makes for better debugging, and consistent naming across tools when they have to create names for you.